# JQuery carousel or gallery with different albums

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gallery

I am looking for a jQuery gallery or slider that would allow me to have different albums. Basically i want multiple jQuery galleries and don't want it to load up a new page to see new content.

Im not looking for anything fancy, just the capability of links above the content. I know html, css, I am familiar with javascript, and i willing to do my research on ajax or any other methods you may suggest, So customizing shouldn't be a problem.

Thanks guys for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

Most jQuery gallery plugins can handle having multiple galleries on the same page.

I would combine that with a simple jQuery tab plugin ([like this one](https://gist.github.com/1165391)) to get the result you want.